# Unable to show images in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript to show images .I have 5 images but unable to display them.My code is as follows:

```
function set()
{
    var i;  
    for(i=1; i<=5; i++)
    {
        var image = "<img src=images/sl + i + />";  
        document.getElementById('slider').innerHTML = image;
    }
}
setInterval("set()","500");


<div id="slider">   
    <img src="images/sl1.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Your `set()` function is going to very rapidly replace each image. Is that intentional?

Comment: @MattBall testing purposes probably!

Comment: You may want to consider changing the src in your img tag, rather than updating the content of your slider div, as the latter may cause flickering.

Answer (score 4):

Change -

```
var image = "<img src=images/sl + i + />";
```

To -

```
var image = "<img src=images/sl" + i + "/>";
```

Also I believe you need to append image format in this too`(jpg | png etc)`

EDIT --

```
var image = "<img src=images/sl" + i +".jpg"+" style='width:500px;height:300px;' />";
```

Comment: You might also want to quote the attribute value: `"<img src='images/sl" + i + ".jpg'/>"`

Comment: @MattBall: Because the initial HTML includes one: `<img src="images/sl1.jpg" />`.  It seems likely that the replacement images also have extensions.

Comment: @Swapnesh thnx for your reply but its also not working ...I have different size of images in my |Images Folder|...???

Comment: what image size has to do with this??

Comment: @UmerBest have you included the image extension as well..as I mentioned??

Comment: @Swapnesh ... I want width="500px;" and height="300px";

Comment: @UmerBest: If the images are now appearing but at the wrong size, then swapnesh has answered your question correctly and you should accept his answer.  If you subsequently want to control the sizes of the images, that's a new and different question.

Comment: @UmerBest Please check my edit...I included the IMAGE EXTENSION part..set it according to yours :)

Comment: Thank you so much for giving me ur time @Swapnesh I put ur code but now only last image show loop not working .....???

Comment: @UmerBest bcoz ur over riding the same variable, chk the logical part too

Comment: @UmerBest: dystroy's answer solves the problem of only the last image showing.

Comment: @RichieHindle thx for the support and being active on the thread :)

Comment: Help me loop not working 
<img width="500" height="300" style="margin-left:400px;" src="images/sl5.jpg">

loog run and just show the 5th image sl5???????

Comment: @UmerBest It is an another question..accept this one as it qualifies for the above question

Answer (score 2):

You're always putting the same image right now, the one of end of loop. I can propose this code :

```
var i = 0;
function set(){
    var image = "<img src=images/sl" + i + "/>";  
    document.getElementById('slider').innerHTML = image;
    i = (i+1)%5;
}
setInterval(set, 500);
```

I fixed a few other bugs/problems. Never pass a string as first argument to `setInterval`, pass the name of the function or a function expression. And the second needed argument is a number, it doesn't make sense to pass a string literal.

But it would have been cleaner to define the `img` element in the HTML part of your code and just change the `src` property instead of the whole slide inner HTML. It would also tell to the browser to change the display only after the image has been loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the filenames of the images are`sl1, sl2,..., sl5` , it should be

`var image = "<img src=images/sl"+i+"/>";`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function set()
{
    var i;  
    for(i=1; i<=5; i++)
    {
        var image = "<img src='images/sl" + i + "'/>";  
        document.getElementById('slider').innerHTML = image;
    }
}
setInterval("set()","500");



<div id="slider">   
    <img src="images/sl1.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Don't pass strings to `setInterval`. It's `eval` in disguise, and unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Your ' i ' variable is part of your string, you need:

```
var image = "<img src=images/sl" + i + "/>";
```